# Python dictionary iterating without prompts

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to make a maze in python, using a dictionary of functions.  I have a file with four maze functions defined, and am using a while loop to iterate through the characters choices. The problem is somewhere in here, because the functions will return an unrecognized command, but not specify the recognized command it returns.  So whatever I type, the puzzle goes from one through four anyway.

```
mazeRoom = {"one" : maze1(x, z), "two" : maze2(x, z), "three" : maze3(x, z), "four" : maze4(x, z)}
key = "one"
while key != "five":
    roomInMaze = mazeRoom[key]
    x = roomInMaze[0]
    z = roomInMaze[1]
    key = roomInMaze[2]
```

The room functions return something like this, only with different numbers:

```
if d1 == "west":
    return x, z, "two"
elif d1 == "south":
    return x, z, "four"
```

Any help, which doesn't call for me to define classes, would be incredibly appreciated!

Comment: You would need to help us understand exactly which line you are having issues with? It does not seem like you have given complete code either, where is the user input?

Comment: Your iteration appears to be based on a key coming from `roomInMaze`, which you do not show.  Why would it *not* iterate differently?

Comment: So I added the rest of my code and changed the key reassignment so that it assigns to the third returned object, but it still doesn't work.  The user input is in the room function, under the direction prompt.

Comment: that's a _lot_ of code. and it's not formatted properly - it would be easier for people to help you if you only included the code that was actually causing the problem, and formatted it properly

Comment: How would I better format it?  I have two files on my computer, which I combined here.  And when I first posted just one of the functions, I was told I hadn't given complete code.

Comment: your code example only needs to demonstrate the problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you currently have a dictionary of function return values, not a dictionary of functions. You initialise the dictionary mazeRoom using some calls to functions maze1, maze2, etc. These functions are called when the dictionary is constructed, using the values of x and z at the time. Presumably you have defined values for x and z or you would be getting an error message.

To check this, immediately after initializing mazeRoom, print it's value - you'll see the values for "one" is a list or tuple that was returned by the maze1 etc. function, which is clearly not a function reference.

To fix this put just the function name as the dictionary entry, e.g.:

```
mazeRoom = {"one" : maze1, "two" : maze2, "three" : maze3, "four" : maze4}
key = "one"
```

I guess you will have to make some changes to the code that uses this dictionary - no point me trying to code something beyond an illustration like:

```
...
roomFunction = mazeRoom[currentRoom]
roomFunctionValue = roomFunction( x, z )
...
```

If it were me I'd be passing the direction into the function as well as whatever x and z are (do these variables have to be so cryptically named?)

HTH
barny

Comment: This worked!  Thank you for the advice.  The x and z things were simply taking place of arrays I had been passing in, because it would have turned into 10 more lines of code I'd have had to post.